# launch imagePicker from TabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was interested in launching the imagePickerController from a tab bar that contains two other navigation controllers.  I'm doing this because I like the multiple thumbnails on one page. I can't figure out how to place the imagePicker in the tab bar array as it must be launched modally.

```
//load imagePicker
imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.editing = YES;
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;


//add navigation controllers to tab bar controller
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:contactNavController, mapNavController, nil];
```

//Set the tabBarController as rootViewController of Window
    [window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

Let me know if you have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImagePicker inherits from UIViewController so it should be fine to just add it to the array you are creating for tabBarController.viewcontrollers.